# Arbitrary depth nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

how do I turn the following into a recursive function that can accumulate a list of lists in an arbitrary-depth fashion?

```
def do_list(n):
    ls = []

    for a in range(10):
        for b in range(10):
            for c in range(10):
                ls.append([a, b, c])

    return ls
```

For instance `do_list(10, 4)` would do:

```
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            for d in range(10):
                ls.append([a, b, c, d])
```

and `do_list(10, 5)` would do:

```
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            for d in range(10):
                for e in range(10):
                    ls.append([a, b, c, d, e])
```

Comment: Check out `itertools.product`, specifically `product(range(10), repeat=whatever)`

Comment: My bad. I used python because I need pseudo-code to implement this function in other languages, so my question is really "how to i write such function" and not "how do i solve this problem with the tools provided specifically by Python".

Comment: @pistacchio the documentation for `itertools.product` provides a possible way to implement this function: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product. Have a look, maybe you can adapt it to other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the actual question how to turn this into a recursive function, try something like this:

```
def do_list(n):
    if n <= 0:
        yield []
    else:
        for res in do_list(n-1):
            for x in range(10):
                yield [*res, x]

for x in do_list(5):
    print(x)
```

Basically, if `n` is zero (or less), you just yield an empty list, and otherwise you generate all the results for `n-1`, and append each of the numbers to each of those. Note that this is a *generator* function using `yield`, but you can just as well collect the results in a list and then return that list (for larger values of `n` this may not be wise, though):

```
def do_list(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        result = []
        for res in do_list(n-1):
            for x in range(10):
                result.append(res + [x])
        return result
```

However, for this specific function, and using Python, you should probably rather use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=5):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Since I'm looking for the most plain algorithm to make it easier to port to other languages, could you please edit your answer in order to actually return a list of lists (avoid the generator) and avoiding the spread operator that is also python-specific? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

def do_list(n, d):
    return list(itertools.product(*(range(n) for _ in range(d))))
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/KnottySnowDatum)

@tobias_k idea may be even better, use the repeat feature of the funtion instead of a generator:

```
def do_list(n, d):
    return list(itertools.product(range(n), repeat=d))
```

Comment: My bad. I used python because I need pseudo-code to implement this function in other languages, so my question is really "how to i write such function" and not "how do i solve this problem with the tools provided specifically by Python".